# Create subdomain in microsoft azure

Tags: php, azure, subdomain, azure-web-app-service

I want to create a sub-domain in Microsoft Azure cloud account where i can put a blog for my website.

For example if my domain is **example.com** where i have hosted by main website file but i want to create a sub-domain like **blog.example.com** where i can put a blog for my website.

What i have tried so is like this. I have created 2 different app resource . i have hosted my main website content in one app in other i have put my blog file code.

I can access my main website but can't access the blog by using **blog.example.com**. I have tried to use the custom sub-domain but it not working.

Answer (score 0):

You'll also need to add a CNAME record pointing to your blog app's default domain name.

[image]

Then navigate to your app service via the [Azure portal](http://portal.azure.com), and add your subdomain as the app's hostname.

[image]

Comment: Will it create a directory with the name blog where i can put my blog files?

Comment: I did what you have explained but now both blog.xxx.com & xxx.com are same now.

Comment: i'm trying to create a subdomain like you said in Azure, i already have a www.myapp.com but i want other like mail.myapp.com. I have no idea how to do that. :/